# Xcode 6.3.1 crashes when opening existing project

Tags: xcode6

I updated Xcode to the latest version via the App Store, as it normal.

I am unable to open any existing project.

I have deleted all Derived Data and have restarted my laptop. Still crashing. And, I have no 3rd party plug ins.

I am including most of the dump. Didn't include the binary images data.

It appears that it might be related to the interface builder. The one app that I want to open, has the Storyboard as the foremost tab.

Thanks for any help in solving this.

---

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D1002
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-7702/Foundation/Utilities/IBFoundationAdditions.m:3148
Details:  No object for "NSFont" key.
Object:   <NSDictionary>
Method:   +ib_strictDictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ffa00c39650>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
```

0  0x000000010520cbfa -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:message    Format:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
      1  0x0000000103f6ab9f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      2  0x0000000103f6ae8e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      3  0x000000010b307ab6 +[NSDictionary(IBDictionaryAdditions)     ib_strictDictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:] (in IBFoundation)
      4  0x000000010fb0e22f IBTextAttributesWithFontColorShadowAndAlignment (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
      5  0x000000010fb0e000 __48+[IBViewControllerPlaceholderStyle defaultStyle]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
      6  0x00007fff8d1adc13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
      7  0x00007fff8d1adb26 dispatch_once_f (in libdispatch.dylib)
      8  0x000000010fb0dd8e +[IBViewControllerPlaceholderStyle defaultStyle] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
      9  0x000000010fb0e458 IBDrawViewPlaceholder (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
     10  0x00000001141e23f9 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)

Comment: I know this won't make you feel any better, but you should file a bug with Apple via http://bugreporter.apple.com.  Xcode engineers need to be made aware that developers are hitting crashes like this.  There's also an Xcode 6.4 beta available right now, so you can grab that and see if your crashing behavior goes away.

Comment: I would start by renaming `~/Library/Developer/Xcode` and then `~/Library/Application Support/Xcode` to see if it's a setting/plugin causing the problem.  It's easy to upset Xcode...

Comment: I have commented on the crashes. and I have a similar question on the Apple forums. Am downloading 6.2 as I need to get something done! Will file the bug report though, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by fixing another issue. OS X app store kept crashing on installation of 10.10. Solved it by downloading 10.10 from Apple directly.

Then, the issue with Xcode just simply went away! And, now app store app works right. Must have been some corruption in the app store itself.